# Python Requests - URL changes between params as text vs params as dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

I'm using Python Requests to call an API using GET

I generate a signature using hmac and hashlib which results in a signature that looks like:

```
4epwTDKhWcIJL6bMM5f2hmBrOoXXIGD9UwX8ErfYzqU%3D
```

When I use Requests and specify the params as a string, the API call is successful because the signature is used as-is and doesn't change.

However when I use Requests and specify the params as a dictionary, the signature above is somehow URL encoded again, resulting in the % being encoded to %25, causing the signature to display as follows (note the %25):

```
4epwTDKhWcIJL6bMM5f2hmBrOoXXIGD9UwX8ErfYzqU%253D
```

For more context, here is the string params:

```
url = 'https://example.com/API'
payload = '&parameterA=valueA&parameterB=valueB&parameterC=valueC&  apikey='+apikey+'&salt='+salt+'&signature='+sig
#payload = {'parameterA': 'valueA', 'parameterB': 'valueB', 'apikey': apikey, 'salt': salt, 'signature': sig}
r = requests.get(url, params=payload)
print r.url
```

results in a URL of:

```
https://example.com/API&
&parameterA=valueA
&parameterB=valueB
&apikey=0e1026af-40ce-e354-f1f2-72d280ca122
&salt=12345
&signature=4epwTDKhWcIJL6bMM5f2hmBrOoXXIGD9UwX8ErfYzqU%3D
```

Now, the dictionary params:

```
url = 'https://example.com/API'
payload = {'parameterA': 'valueA', 'parameterB': 'valueB', 'apikey': apikey, 'salt': salt, 'signature': sig}
r = requests.get(url, params=payload)
print r.url
```

results in a URL of:

```
https://example.com/API
&signature=4epwTDKhWcIJL6bMM5f2hmBrOoXXIGD9UwX8ErfYzqU%253D
&salt=12345
&apikey=0e1026af-40ce-e354-f1f2-72d280ca122
&parameterA=valueA
&parameterB=valueB
```

Note again that the % in the signature has changed to %25

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing a dictionary to `params` it gets url encoded. Your string is url encoded already so it gets double encoded, resulting in a malformed 'signature'.
You can use [`urllib.unquote`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote) to decode `sig` (or you can just replace `'%3D'` with `'='`)

```
payload = { 
    'parameterA': 'valueA', 'parameterB': 'valueB', 
    'apikey': apikey, 'salt': salt, 'signature': urllib.unquote(sig) 
}
```

Note that in python3 `unquote` is located in `urllib.parse`.

Comment: Thanks for this! I knew it was something small. Turns out I URL encode when generating the signature, which was rather premature. I need to check my demo code in future. I appreciate the insight, thanks!